# Element disappear in Scrollview

Tags: android, react-native

I want to create a view having scrollview inside and then I want 3 cards inside that scrollview. like this `View > ScrollView > Cards` but when I put card in scrollview, card disappers, but appear if scrollview is commented. I have tried giving `flex:1` to parent View, scrollview but it doesn't work

here is code

```
 <View style={styles.section3}>
      <ScrollView horizontal={true}>
        <View style={styles.card}></View>
        <View style={styles.card}></View>
        <View style={styles.card}></View>
        <View style={styles.card}></View>
      </ScrollView>
    </View>
```

styles

```
  scrollView: {
    // flex: 2,
    backgroundColor: 'black',
  },
  card: {
    // flex: 4,
    width: '90%',
    height: '70%',
    marginHorizontal: '5%',
    marginVertical: '10%',
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    borderRadius: 25,
    opacity: 0.9,
    top: -15,
  },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

main issue is % values for horizontal properties like width, marginHorizontal. If ScrollView is horizontal react can't calculate the area to render view because it's not fixed, same for vertical properties like height, marginVertical if orientation is vertical.

Here is the changes I made, mainly with horizontal properties.

```
  section3: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  card: {
    // flex: 4,
    width: 190, // or some other value
    height: '70%',
    marginHorizontal: 16,
    marginVertical: '10%',
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    borderRadius: 25,
    opacity: 0.9,
    top: -15,
  },
```

and I personally avoid using percentage values for width, height etc.

I think they are good when we know the area parent view's gonna cover on the screen.

Comment: than how could i make it resposive if I can't give value in %.

Comment: it rendered but it is not scrolling. scrollbar is also not visible. which is visible for 1 sec on render

Comment: You can give fix value or if you want to design based on screen's **width/height** you can use [useWindowDimensions](https://reactnative.dev/docs/usewindowdimensions) and set style. Like here for width you do this `width: (screenWidth * 90) / 100` and for `marginHorizontal: (screenWidth * 5) / 100`

Comment: @AqsaMaan I used the code you shared and It's scrolling for me.

Comment: it's not working for me. what should i do?is there any replacement for scrollview in react native?

Comment: Is the code you shared complete? I have no issue in scrolling. Also make sure there are no other components that depends on swipe gesture like side drawer.

Comment: yes this is the only code and there are literellay no other components. it's not working on real device also. did u checked it on expo? i'm working in react-native-cli

Comment: I'm too using **react-native-cli** and testing on real device.